# Running Two Threads in an Android Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, spreadsheet

I would like to create a service that when started, initializes a connection to google spreadsheets and then periodically sends data to the spreadsheet from a database.

Is it possible to create two threads:
One that connects to google spreadsheets and a second that check for changes in the database and updates the spreadsheet.

I was thinking of running the first thread (connecting to google spreadsheets) from the onCreate and the second from the onStartCommand. Is this bad practice? Does anyone have any feedback about how I can do this?

Thanks, and please let me know if anything I have said is unclear.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first thread? What will it do?

Comment: The first thread establishes a connection to Google Spreadsheets. Which about 30-40 seconds.
The second simply adds data to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to run two threads? Your work seems to be sequential: first get data from the database, then post it to a spreadsheet. You might save a second or two if you are already authenticated to Google Docs by the time you get the database data, but if this needs to run in a background service, it won't be visible. And since it seems this only needs to run from time to time, you should schedule your service to start at certain intervals using `AlarmManager`, and let it shut itself down once it's done it's work. Consider using an `IntentService` for this, it will start a background thread to do work and shut down automatically.

Comment: What is the benefit of IntentService over Service?

Comment: A Service doesn't automatically start a worker thread and it won't shut itself down automatically when done (you need to call `stopSelf()`). An IntentService uses a queue for the requests it receives and runs them (one after another) in a background thread, shutting itself down when done. Basically it does the right thing without you having to worry about the details.